# compositor make empty image

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Dont have any explain... please, see my archive. https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4b4yf79NLDUm2Q
[image]

Comment: Because you have a strip in Video Sequencer ... Blender calculates Compositor than continue to Sequencer to calculate data if any ... delete the strip or disable Sequencer in Output Properties > Post Processing panel.

Comment: thanks, it resolve!